# Static website private content Amazon S3 and Cloudfront - css, js and images not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set the acl for the origin access identity on all objects as read. I have set up the bucket policy for the OAI. The only way I can get the css, or anything else apart from the html, to work is if I reference it with the the full signed URL ie **domain name**/css/main.css?**parameters of signed url**, in the index.html.
I have ensured that all files have the correct content type.
Is this standard practice? Do I have to reference every image, css, js file this way with the signed url?
I have been searching for days on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

bucket policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": " Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity **identity canoncal**"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::**bucket**/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: when you are not using the full s3 url, how are you referencing them?

Comment: Hi EJ,Thanks for the response. For example css: I tried referencing them relatively as you would normally. This is ok if it is public but when it's a private distribution it doesn't work. I then tried using just the domain name(base url) to reference them ie mysite.cloudfront.net/css/mystyle.css. This didn't work. I can access it by using the fully signed url ie mysite.cloudfront.net/css/mystyle.css?gggjggj.... It seems strange that every image, css, js file needs this.

Comment: My work around is this: I figure that I dont need to protect my css, image and js files. I created a new bucket and placed them all in there and made them public then referenced those from my private site. This works. This will probably suit me as I will be creating more buckets that can reference the same files.

Answer (score 2):

My work around is this: I figure that I dont need to protect my css, image and js files. I created a new bucket and placed them all in there and made them public then referenced those from my private site. This works. This will probably suit me as I will be creating more buckets that can reference the same files.

Comment: Amazing, I couldn't find anything at all on stackoverflow about this.  But this works for me too, if I have to use a second, public bucket to get my css urls to work, so be it.